# How to enable/disable a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I've got a relatively simple WPF application. The idea is to present a list of items to the user; for each item there is a checkbox to select/deselect the item.

My code, simplified, looks a bit like this:

```
 class Thing { /* ... */ };
 public static int SelectedCount { get; set; }
 public class SelectableThing
 {
        private bool _selected;
        public bool Selected { 
            get { return _selected; }
            set { _selected = value; if (value) { SelectedCount++; } else { SelectedCount--; } } 
        }
        public Thing thing { get; set; }
 };
 private ObservableCollection<SelectableThing> _selectableThings;
 public Collection<SelectableThing> { get { return _selectableThings; } }
 <DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Path=SelectableThings}">
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Selected}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Thing.name}"/>
 </DataGrid>
 <Button Content="{Binding Path=SelectedTestCount}" Click="someFunc" />
```

So the idea is that the button content should show the count of tests selected. This should be accomplished because whenever SelectableThing.Selected is set, it should increment/decrement the SelectedCount as appropriate.

However, as far as I can tell the behavior doesn't work. The button text displays "0", regardless of selecting/deselecting items in the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using viewmodels or just code-behind?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is a little hairy since you have multiple view-model classes involved.  Here's a crack at the code to solve this.  The only thing I'm missing is that the DataGrid doesn't seem to update your items until you leave the row.

[image: At start, before any edits. The save button is disabled, and the count is zero]
[image: After some edits. The save button is enabled, and the count is updated]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectableThings}"
                  Grid.Row="0" Margin="6">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsSelected"
                                        Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=SelectedTestCount}"
                Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                Grid.Row="1" Width="75" Height="23"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,6"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thing class:

```
public class Thing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<SelectableThing> selectableThings;
    private DelegateCommand saveCommand;

    public Thing(IEnumerable<SelectableThing> selectableThings)
    {
        this.selectableThings = new List<SelectableThing>(selectableThings);
        this.SelectableThings =
            new ObservableCollection<SelectableThing>(this.selectableThings);

        this.SaveCommand = this.saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            o => Save(),
            o => SelectableThings.Any(t => t.IsSelected)
            );

        // Bind children to change event
        foreach (var selectableThing in this.selectableThings)
        {
            selectableThing.PropertyChanged += SelectableThingChanged;
        }

        SelectableThings.CollectionChanged += SelectableThingsChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SelectableThing> SelectableThings
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int SelectedTestCount
    {
        get { return SelectableThings.Where(t => t.IsSelected).Count(); }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    private void Save()
    {
        // Todo: Implement
    }

    private void SelectableThingChanged(object sender,
        PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTestCount");
            saveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private void SelectableThingsChanged(object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SelectableThing selectableThing in
            e.OldItems ?? new List<SelectableThing>())
        {
            selectableThing.PropertyChanged -= SelectableThingChanged;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTestCount");
        }

        foreach (SelectableThing selectableThing in
            e.NewItems ?? new List<SelectableThing>())
        {
            selectableThing.PropertyChanged += SelectableThingChanged;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTestCount");
        }
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

SelectableThing class:

```
public class SelectableThing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private bool isSelected;

    public SelectableThing(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Bind `Command` to an `ICommand`.  Set your `CanExecute` on the `ICommand` to return `false` when your condition isn't satisified.

In the setter for that `IsSelected` property, when the value changes, raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event.

The `Command` binding on a `Button` automatically enables/disables the button based on the result of `CanExecute`.

For more information on how to do this, including an implementation of `ICommand` that you could use here, see [this mini-MVVM tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592013/trying-to-understand-of-dependencyproperty/7599716#7599716) I wrote up for another question.

To fill out the implementaiton of `CanExecute`, I'd use something like Linq's `.Any` method.  Then you don't have to bother checking `Count`, and can terminate the loop early if you find that any item is checked.

For example:

```
this.SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);

// ...

private void Save(object unusedArg)
{
    // Todo: Implement
}

private bool CanSave(object unusedArg)
{
    return SelectableThings.Any(t => t.IsSelected);
}
```

Or since it is short, use a lambda inline:

```
this.SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save,
    o => SelectableThings.Any(t => t.IsSelected)
    );
```

Comment: The bit about raising `CanExecuteChanged` based on `IsSelected` changing might be tricky, since it looks like you're using a collection of child view models.  You could subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged` on each, and forward the event to `this.SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`.  Let me know if you have troubles figuring this part out.

Comment: Also note I suggest you name the property `IsSelected`.  You should follow this convention when naming boolean values (Is, Can, Has, etc).

Comment: I've amended the original question to reflect your input; can you let me know your thoughts on it?

Comment: @StephenGross: While using a `static` member might work, it is a hack.  You couldn't support multiple instances of whatever class hold that property (`Thing`?).  It will also be harder to write unit tests for this code.  I'm also not sure if WPF can bind to static properties or not, or if `INotifyPropertyChanged` would work on it.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I used a static int is that otherwise you can't change it from inside SelectableThing.Selected.set().

Comment: @Stephen: I've added some code to show exactly what I mean, since this problem is sort of nasty.  My solution is about as close as you're going to get to a clean one without using a toolkit that wraps some of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff for you.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking through your amended recommendation. It seems like there should be a simpler way... Isn't it possible to have a 'int SelectedCount' attribute that gets set whenever the boolean IsSelected changes? If it is, then I should be able to bind controls to the SelectedCount and drive them that way.

Comment: @Stephen: The problem is that every time a single check box changes, you need to update the button/text box.  The only way to do this is to subscribe to all the events.  WPF subscribes to the event per-checkbox, but doesn't have a simple way to subscribe to all the events in aggregate.  You might look into using a trigger on the check boxes to solve it, though you might need some back-end converter code to get that to work (with implementations similar to the Linq I've stuck in this answer).

Comment: @Stephen: If you get it to work with a different method than the one I suggest, I recommend you add it as a separate answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the Content of the button to a field in your viewmodel and fire the OnChanged method for that field every time another item is selected or unselected.  Bind the IsEnabled to a boolean field in your view model and set it to true/false as appropriate to enable or disable the button.

Comment: I've amended the original question to try this out, but probably have got it wrong (!)...