# How to enable/disable WPF button based on method return

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I need to enable/disable a WPF button based on the return of a method.

I have a `HasPermission` method that tells me if the user can or not click on that button.

I've seen that I could use `Command => CanExecute` to avoid the execution of the action. Seen here:

[How to enable/disable a button in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921280/how-to-enable-disable-a-button-in-wpf)

My question is, I have a lot of Windows in which I'll be checking for the permission, is this the best approach? Will I really have to write from `2` to `N` commands for every window I have?

Is there any way to make this `global`? 

For instance, could I create the generic commands (Search/Create/...) and then only get the window it was called from and pass it to my `HasPermission` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely make a static class that holds static commands, and refer to those from anywhere in your XAML.

It goes like this:

```
public static class GlobalCommands
{
   //ICommand can be DelegateCommand, RelayCommand... whatever floats your boat.
   public static ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

   //Implementation, and more static commands...
}
```

Then in some view:

```
<UserControl ...>
   ...
   <Button Content="Search" Command="{x:Static infra:GlobalCommands.SearchCommand}" />
   ...
</UserControl>
```

Of course, `infra:` is a xmlns namespace mapping to `GlobalCommands`' namespace.

Comment: Got it, but how would I tell the window the button was called from? Thanks.

Comment: @eestein You'd pass it as `CommandParameter`. I'd make the viewmodel implement some ISearchable interface and pass that to the command.