# Data Binding with ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

and I want him to take data from another class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataContext = _myList;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myList = AnotherClass.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Why this way doesn't work? The only way to do that is to write something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myList.Clear();
        foreach (var version in AnotherClass.SomeMethod())
        {
            _myList.Add(version);
        }
    }
```

or I can do it without calling of Add method?

Comment: I would try changing it to `public ObservableCollection<string> myList 
{ get; set; }` and initializing it in the constructor.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DataContext property before calling InitializeComponent()?

Comment: Neither of these suggestions will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF isn't designed for you to keep switching out the `DataContext`.  It relies on you sticking with one data context, and for the data that's bound to it to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Because of this, it is better to bind to complex objects than directly to data.  Then all you have to do is update your XAML bindings, add properties that raise the `PropertyChanged` event on `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you're done.  You won't have to set bindings directly on controls after that.

Here's an answer I've given to a different question that ends up giving a full tutorial for that approach: [Trying to understand of DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592013/trying-to-understand-of-dependencyproperty/7599716#7599716)

And here's one way to start doing that with your code, with only slight changes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyList = AnotherClass.SomeMethod();
    }

    public PropertyChangedEvent PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the updated XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
          Width="120" Height="23"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Margin="210,12,0,0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use INotifyPropertyChanged pattern or DependecyProperty to notify binding about changes to _myList.

More about this pattern can be found in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) article.